# Default SuperUser not adding to database on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

Ive added asp.net Identity to my application, and i've setup my startup class to add roles (if not present) and to add a default SuperUser.

My problem is that when the application runs, it creates the roles in the database as per the code, but isn't adding the SuperUser details.

What am I missing?

I followed the instructions here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

I also deleted the rows in the AspNetRoles table and checked that they were recreated upon startup, which they were showing that the function is being called upon startup.

In the startup.cs file

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandUsers();
    }

    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));


        // In Startup i am creating first Super Role and creating a default Super User    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Super"))
        {

            // first we create Admin role  
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Super";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                  

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "Admin";
            user.Email = "admin@transsafe.co.nz";


            string userPWD = "L1llo1.";

            var result = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            //Add default User to Role Admin   
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Super");

            }
        }

        // creating Creating Manager role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Administrator";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        // creating Creating Manager role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Manager";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        // creating Creating Employee role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "User";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }
    }
}
```

I expect the user "Admin" to be in the AspNetUsers table as well as the roles created in the AspNetRoles table.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to change this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser();
user.UserName = "Admin";
user.Email = "admin@transsafe.co.nz";
```

Over to this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "Transsafe", UserOrganisation = "Transsafe" };
```

And it worked fine at first.  Then when I retested it failed again.  Open to any ideas.